# Conditional probabilities from two data sets using software

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, software

I am working on a project where I have two pieces of information for each individual $i$, $x_i$ and $y_i$. There are $n$ individuals in total.

I want to find the probability that $y_i \geq y_j$ given $x_i \geq x_j$, for all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$.

I feel doing it manually would not be possible and even undesirable, because the $n$ in my case is more than 100, but I do not know any way to let some software find this for me.

Is it possible in Microsoft Excel or IBM SPSS, as I usually use these two? If yes how? If no, where can I do this? I am currently learning the basics of R Studio and Python too.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient#Algorithms.